Modifying dashes within quotations
If I'm quoting a sentence that uses a different type of dash than the one I prefer, is it permissible to modify the dashes within the quoted sentence to make them consistent with my preference?
Let us assume I want to quote the following sentence:

In a defiant and lengthy TV address on Thursday, Yoon defended his
shock decision last week to impose martial law – a move designed to
suspend political activities and press and civic freedoms – describing
it as a legitimate “act of governance” and denied attempting to foment
insurrection.

— Guardian international staff, 12 Dec 2024
When quoting this sentence, can I change the spaced en dashes to (spaced or unspaced) em dashes for better consistency with the rest of the text? Or is that regarded as a sort of tampering with the quoted text? In my research, style guides do not address this. I would prefer to be able to modify the dashes but I am wary of doing so in the absence of any convention in my support. Is there any punctuation convention or style guide that answers this question?

When it gets to such fine detail, there are always going to be issues like this to decide. Are you using the same font, the same point size? What if you're using a typewriter without the same font? / Should you use an image rather than a retype? The particular issue you mention must break with recommendations one way or the other ... consistency throughout your document or strict accuracy of quote. I'd make the tiny adjustment, and make a note explaining what you have done. And then stop worrying; life's too short to focus on such minutiae.

I'd say don't make any such "tiny adjustment". If your context allows you to reproduce the text more "accurately", you should always do that. Otherwise there will be times when you erroneously change things for stylistic reasons without realizing that your cited author knew what he was doing, and made his choice for a reason you might not be qualified to argue against. God save us from ignoramuses  who "correct" Shakespeare's immortal words!

You have to decide if you want an accurate quote or if your preferences take precedent. How can it not be wise to leave it as is?

APA is pretty clear: "Any other changes ... must be explicitly indicated." You can change anything you like as long as you say what you've done.

By the way, using printers’ terminology one would express your question in terms of setting the em dashes open (with space either side) or closed.

I don't think anyone is going to be concerned with minor things like the regularization of dashes, or changing the white space between sentences from one space to two, or vice versa,  especially when the source is a newspaper. If you go down that path, you will start asking yourself if you should retain the column width of the original, and hyphenations at line-breaks. Your responsibility is to quote faithfully the words in the text and to quote enough of the text that what you quote is not distorted by lack of context.

APA allows certain changes, for example: "Some punctuation marks at the end of a quotation may be changed to fit the syntax of the sentence in which the quotation appears, as long as meaning is not changed". Regularizing dashes is far less significant than such repunctuation.  The principle is "do not change the meaning".

Just do minor changes, why not?

If you follow The Chicago Manual of Style, then yes—you can change the spaced en dashes to (spaced or unspaced) em dashes:

12: Quotations and Dialogue
12.7: Permissible changes to punctuation, capitalization, and spelling

En dashes or hyphens used as em dashes may be changed to em dashes, with any space before or after the dash or hyphen eliminated as needed
(see 6.91–98). Hyphens may be changed to en dashes in number ranges or
other contexts where an en dash may be appropriate (for use of the en
dash, see 6.82–90).

Source: The Chicago Manual of
Style
(login required)

This is one among scores of other permissible changes elaborated on throughout the book.

It seems only fair that em-dashes may also be changed to en-dashes, to match the choice of many Brits in the rest of a document.
